# Help with query to assign conversion

Tags: mariadb, query

I would need help with my SQL foo. I have 3 tables like this

```
TBL LEAD
id
email
activity_tracking_id
...

TBL ACTIVITY_TRACKING
id
uid
created_ad
action
referer
...

TBL BUYERS
id
email
...
```

Table activity reference itselft using uid field. Buyer is related by buyer.email to lead.email. Pageview is a value of activity_tracking.action

As a lead navigate a website, a log in TBL ACTIVITY TRACKING is registered. Referer is important here, I want to know how many buyers came from each distinct referer (Facebook, Instagram, Google, etc). Problem is, referer is external only on first pageview, afterward, the referer is the previous page on the site, following navigation.

Also, a user can visit again using a new referer or the same, I need only 1 once  per lead per referer.

How should I build my query to have something like this :

```
Referer | Count
Instagram 12
Facebook  25
Google    20
```

For info, I'm using MariaDB.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: a) How is `buyers` related to the other tables? b) It's not clear how pageviews are related to these 3 tables. Is there a separate `pageviews` table or do they correspong to `activity_tracking`? c) It would help to add the full `CREATE TABLE` statements, so the column types and constraints (especially FOREIGN KEY) are clearly shown, and a few sample rows. See the advice on the link in the comment above.

Comment: Hi @ypercube, buyer is related by buyer.email to lead.email. Pageview is a value of activity_tracking.action

Comment: Please edit the question and add the info requested there.